# Angular select tag easiest way to display different text in options than what's bound to ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

I have a select like this:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select"> 
    <span class = "input-label"> Security:  </span> 
    <select name="scopeEnumId" ng-model="task.scopeEnumId">
        <option>General</option>
        <option>Very Restricted</option>
        <option>Staff-Only Access</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Now this makes the task object to look something like this when chosen:

```
{
   scopeEnumId:'Very Restricted'
}
```

**Can I have it that the user sees: General , Very Restricted, Staff-Only Access
but the object looks like this:**

```
{
   scopeEnumId:'enum_restricted'
}
```

or

```
{
   scopeEnumId:'enum_staff'
}
```

Something like

```
<option>enum_restricted as Very Restricted</option>
```

I know I can do it in javascript but I want to know if there is something built in Angular. I didn't find anything, but that doesn't mean anything :)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/emn28gfk/

Comment: Can you share with js code, so that we can see your try and it will be easy to make it in angular.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emn28gfk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'value' attribute on your option tags to set the desired value of scopeEnumId.

Example:

```
<option value="veryRestricted">Very Restricted  </option>
```

would map to:

```
{scopeEnumId : 'veryRestricted'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are just trying to just trying to convert your camelCase to Regular Case, a filter would work:

```
app.filter('regularCase', function () {
  return function (id) {
    //convert camelCase to Regular Case
    return id.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); });
  };
});
```

That way, you could do:

```
<option>{{scopeEnumId | regularCase}}</option>
```

Comment: no i was actually looking to have the ng-model have different values, ill update the question to make it clear